# Twilio Conversation Fatal error when trying to send message?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to do a group conversation following the twilio samples online. I have the conversation and the people are connected (I think) but when I go send a message I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 412] Unable to create record: Group MMS activation failed in
```

Does anyone have any working samples of a working conversation in PHP? If you want I can post my full code (minus the keys and phone numbers)

**UPDATE:**

Code to set up conversation:

```
$conversation = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations
                                          ->create([
                                                       "friendlyName" => "RawesomePaws"
                                                   ]
                                          );
```

I then added the Twilio phone and 3 other SMS phone #'s

```
$participant = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHb61ad48141884350896047adc23XXXX")
                                         ->participants
                                         ->create([
                                                      "identity" => "Rawesome Orders",
                                                      "messagingBindingProjectedAddress" => "+1408840XXXX"
                                                  ]
                                         );

$participant = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHb61ad48141884350896047adc237XXXX")
                                         ->participants
                                         ->create([
                                                      "messagingBindingAddress" => "+1408409XXXX"
                                                  ]
                                         );

$participant = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHb61ad48141884350896047adc237XXXX")
                                         ->participants
                                         ->create([
                                                      "messagingBindingAddress" => "+1815210XXXX"
                                                  ]
                                         );

$participant = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHb61ad48141884350896047adc237XXXX")
                                         ->participants
                                         ->create([
                                                      "messagingBindingAddress" => "+1408540XXXX"
                                                  ]
                                         );
```

Now that the conversation is set up, I try to send a group message:

```
$message = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHb61ad48141884350896047adc237XXXX")
                                     ->messages
                                     ->create([
                                                  "body" => 'Message Body',
                                                  "author" => 'Rawesome Orders',
                                             ]
                                     );
```

and here is the output when I am in the terminal:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 412] Unable to create record: Group MMS activation failed in /home/customer/www/sirota-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php(223): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...')
#1 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Rest/Conversations/V1/Conversation/MessageList.php(57): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Conversations/...', Array, Array, Array)
#2 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/sms_SendMessage.php(15): Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList->create(Object(Twilio\Values))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php on line 88
```

**Update 2**
This is the complete log from phpLog

```
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] -- BEGIN Twilio API Request --
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Request Method: POST
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Request URL: /v1/Conversations/CHb61ad48141884350896047adc237cf45/Messages
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Request Headers: 
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] User-Agent: twilio-php/6.16.0 (PHP 7.3.27)
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Accept-Charset: utf-8
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] Accept: application/json
[24-Apr-2021 01:11:59 UTC] -- END Twilio API Request --
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Status Code: 412
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Response Headers:
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Date:  Sat, 24 Apr 2021 01:12:00 GMT
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Content-Type:  application/json; charset=utf-8
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Content-Length:  129
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Connection:  keep-alive
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Twilio-Request-Id:  RQbd66fd8e4b548596a430a2646a4376f2
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Twilio-Request-Duration:  0.195
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Access-Control-Expose-Headers:  ETag
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:  true
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] X-Powered-By:  AT-5000
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] X-Shenanigans:  none
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] X-Home-Region:  us1
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] X-API-Domain:  conversations.twilio.com
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=31536000
[24-Apr-2021 01:12:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 412] Unable to create record: Group MMS activation failed in /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php(223): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...')
#1 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Rest/Conversations/V1/Conversation/MessageList.php(57): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Conversations/...', Array, Array, Array)
#2 /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/sms_SendMessage.php(15): Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList->create(Object(Twilio\Values))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/customer/www/XXX-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/Version.php on line 88
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Also the full error message? One other question, are you sending messages to numbers in the US or Canada? They are the only countries that would support Group MMS.

Comment: The messages are in the US only... I will post the code shortly.

Comment: I have updated the original message to include the code I use @philnash

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is that your conversation participant's identity has a space in it, and that may not be allowed. Can you try again with an identity that doesn't have a space and see if that helps?

Comment: @philnash tried changing the identity to   "identity" => "RawesomeOrders", still 412 error

Comment: I am not sure, sorry, I have asked the team at Twilio and will get back to you soon on this.

Comment: @philnash I have had an open ticket for weeks... I'm getting a little aggravated with them. I am wondering if I need a separate number for the conversations or if the 1 twilio number I use for SMS is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the error codes for this are yet to be published, which I will follow up on internally. I have found some documentation for this error though.

> Typical reasons for failure include:
>
> - Less than 3 non-chat participants in the conversation
> - There’s a chat participant in the conversation
> - There’s an existing group conversation with the exact same participants
> - There’s a participant with a `ProjectedAddress` only

Note that a participant with an `Identity` and a `ProjectedAddress` counts as a non-chat participant.

As far as I can see from your code, you have 4 non-chat participants (notably, the limit for group MMS is 4 participants right now), so that is fine. You have one participant with a `ProjectedAddress` and an `Identity`, which is fine. There are no participants with only a `ProjectedAddress`.

That leaves one potential issue, that there is already an existing group with these exact participants.

In order to check what's going on, I would now do a couple of things.

First, double check that these participants were correctly created and none are missing a property, particularly the participant with the `Identity` and `ProjectedAddress`.

Then, check to see if you have an existing conversation object that also has these participants.

If neither of those checks comes up with anything, let me know and I'll escalate the ticket you have open.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did a look and deleted all conversations then started from scratch again and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Perhaps it was that existing conversation with the same participants then. Glad you’re unstuck now!